# может есть какой нибудь генератор кодов который делает такой код

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html2canvas

Этот код работает в canvas и он работает как рисовальщик, в данном случаи он рисует текст , я не знаю где можно найти генератор текстов который бы сгенерировал такой код к примеру я написал reply и вот появляются этот код :

AEMCVIgHgEIgGgFQgCgEAAgDIACgHIADgFIAGgEIAHgBIAIABIAKAFIAHABQAFAAADgDIAHgHIAFgIIAPggIhPiQIAjAAIA7BsIAwhsIAQAAIhOCyQgFALgGAIQgHAIgHAGQgHAFgHADQgIACgHAAgAh8CQIAAjXIAeAAIAAAfIAKgMIANgLQAGgFAJgDQAIgDAKAAQANAAALAFQALAGAGAKQAIAKAEANQAEANAAAPQAAARgFAQQgFAQgJALQgIAMgOAGQgOAHgRAAIgMgBIgKgCIgKgDIgJgFIAABIgAhBg0IgLAGIgKAIIgIAJIAABDQAAAHADAGQADAHAFAEQAGAFAHACQAIADAJAAQAIAAAIgEQAHgFAGgIQAFgIAEgLQADgLAAgNQAAgPgDgNQgDgNgFgIQgGgIgHgFQgHgEgJAAQgHAAgGACgACCBQQgIgDgFgFQgFgFgDgHQgCgHAAgIQAAgKAEgIQAEgIAGgGQAHgGAJgFIATgHIAqgMIAAgKQAAgKgCgHQgCgIgEgEQgEgEgFgCQgGgCgGAAQgIAAgFACQgFACgCADQgDADgBAFIgCAQIgCAGIgFAFQgDABgEAAIgHgBIgFgEIgDgFIgBgIQAAgHAFgHQAFgGAIgFQAIgFAMgCQALgDAMAAQAPAAALADQAKADAHAFQAGAFADAIQADAHAAAJIAAByIgfAAIAAgVIgWAQQgGAEgHACQgHACgKAAQgJAAgHgDgACrACIgNAHIgLAIIgHAJQgDAFAAAGQAAAFACAGQACAFAEADQADAEAFACQAEADAFAAIAKgCIAJgDIARgMIAAg3gAj+BNQgOgGgKgKQgKgKgGgNQgGgOAAgPQAAgQAFgQQAGgQAKgLQAJgLAOgHQAOgGARAAQAPAAANAFQAMAFAJAJQAJAJAFAMQAFALAAANIhyAAQAAAOAEANQAEANAHAJQAHAKAKAFQAKAGAMAAQAKAAAJgDQAJgEAIgFQAHgFAFgHQAFgHADgHIAIAEQgDAMgHAKQgIALgJAHQgKAIgMAFQgLAEgMAAQgQAAgNgGgAjDgWQAAgJgDgHQgDgIgFgFQgGgGgHgDQgHgDgIAAQgHAAgGADQgHADgFAGQgFAFgDAIQgDAHgBAJIBMAAIAAAAgAAxBQIAAjdIAWgIIAIAAIAADlgAmZBQIAAiXIAeAAIAAAdIAJgNIALgKIALgHQAGgCAGAAIAKABIAHAEIAFAGQACADAAAEQAAAHgEAEQgFAEgIAAIgJgBIgKgFIgHgBIgGACIgGAFIgGAHIgGAKIAABog

этот код означает : " reply "

может есть какой нибудь генератор кодов который делает такой код, только не base64